# Application Insights | How to show logs for only the intended function app in application insights?

Tags: logging, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, ilogger

I have a couple of function apps (FunctionApp1 and FunctionApp2). FunctionApp1 sends a message to a service bus queue which is consumed by FunctionApp2.

When the flow is executed, the logs in Application Insights show logs for the combined flow. When I check specific logs for FunctionApp1 in the `Performance` tab of the Application Insights, it shows logs for FunctionApp2 as well and true for vice-versa..

I tried to disable the logging for FunctionApp2 when FunctionApp1 is executed by setting log level in `host.json` file for FunctionApp1 like so:

```
{
    "logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Function.FunctionApp2":"None",
            "default":"debug"
        }
    }
}
```

This disables logs for FunctionApp2 altogether.

How can I set up such that, when requested for logs for FunctionApp1 only its logs are shown and same for the FunctionApp2?

**UPDATE**

I tried setting `EnableDependencyTracking` to false in host.json file for FunctionApp1 like so:

```
{
    "logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "default":"debug"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "enableDependencyTracking": false
        },
        ....
    }
}
```

This didn't work either.

Comment: Can you examine telemetry items (in Logs experience) and see whether there is a custom dimension you could use for such filtering?

Comment: @ZakiMa, I tried to filter with `Operation Name=FunctionApp1`. In the list view it only shows for the provided operation name. But when I drill down on View All Telemetry, it shows logs for FunctionApp2 as well.

Comment: You can try with setting a higher log level to filter information.

Go to Azure portal, Platform features> Function app settings> host.json.


For Function app v2:



{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"logLevel": {
"Function.MyFunctionName.User": "Information",
"Function": "Error"
}
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TelemetryContext` has a property called as [Parent operation Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-context#parent-operation-id). As per the docs it keeps track of telemetry item's immediate parent. Thus, I updated telemetry's parent using custom telemetry like so (Below code was implemented in the FunctionApp2):

```
var dependency = new DependencyTelemetry();
// Appended UTC ticks to GUID to avoid conflicting Azure's generated GUIDs in case any future ParentId matches Azure's already generated GUID.
dependency.Context.Operation.ParentId = $"{Guid.NewGuid():N}{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Ticks}";
_telemetryClient.TrackDependency(dependency);
```

The `DependencyTelemetry` was injected into the function app using Depenedency Injection like so:

```
_telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
```

`TelemetryConfiguration` was added as a service in the `Startup.cs` class:

```
services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>((x) =>
            {
                x.InstrumentationKey = Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                x.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());

            });
```

Refer ApplicationInsight's issue [1152](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1152#issuecomment-518742922) for more details re the code above.

Going back to updating the telemetry operation's parent id, it makes sure that FunctionApp2's telemetry is not linked to FunctionApp1's telemetry.